# GTA 5 Online not detected my Wi-Fi to login in online GTA

Tags: technical-issues, grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

I remember an error that I had for a few days, WiFi never goes online. I clicked to join but it doesn't. I checked the Store and it says no internet so I went to Windows Firewall and ticked everything for GTA 5 to work but the same thing happened when I restarted - I got the same error.

What's going on? I need join to gta online!

[imgur link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcjGu.jpg)

Comment: can someone fix it?